# ggplot: draw segment that goes off the chart's limits

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw a chart with a segment that goes off the limits of the plot. Ggplot simply suppress the segment instead of displaying the visible part of it.

This is an example for illustration:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x1 = 2, x2 = 6, y1 = 10, y2 = 50)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_segment(aes(x = x1, y = y1, xend = x2, yend = y2), data = df) +
    xlim(c(0, 7)) +
    ylim(c(0, 35)) +
    coord_fixed(.1)
```

This is what I want:
[image]

But instead the segment is not drawn and I get the following warning:

```r
Warning message:
Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).
```

I want to keep the chart limits fixed and the `coord_fixed(.1)` setting.

Comment: there's no need to delete posts that are marked as duplicates - they are useful pointers to the best info at the canonical source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `xlim` and `ylim` will remove data that falls outside of the limits. To achieve the desired result set the limits inside `coord_fixed`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x1 = 2, x2 = 6, y1 = 10, y2 = 50)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x1, y = y1, xend = x2, yend = y2), data = df) +
  coord_fixed(.1, xlim= c(0,7), ylim = c(0, 35))
```

[image]